# Get array with results of object method on each item in an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of objects and I want to convert it to an array of the result of a method of each of them.  I can do this just fine, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner / better approach to it maybe?  For example, pretend this is what I'm working with and how I'm doing it now:

```
$objects = array();

$objects[] = new Dog();
$objects[] = new Dog();
$objects[] = new Dog();

$data = array();
foreach ($objects as $obj) {
  $data[] = $obj->myMethod();
}
```

Obviously this isn't super important, but it'd be nice to know about better ways to produce `$data` from `$objects` in the future.  Any ideas?  I was thinking there was some function for this, like `array_map()` or something but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could indeed use PHP's [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do this

```
function cb($obj) { return $obj->myMethod(); }
.
.
$data = array_map(cb, $objects);
```

Comment: In php 5.3 you can use anonymous functions instead of `function cb($obj)`

Comment: ah yeah 5.3 - the version that doesn't run properly in CLI mode for me on Windows 7  :( - but indeed that'd be a better way to do it...

Comment: This does look like the best way to go about it - thanks.  And yeah I like the 5.3 version also but don't have it locally or on the server this is heading to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have php 5.3 or better, the neater way is to use array_map() with anonymous functions:

```
$retArray = array_map(function($o){ $o->myMethod(); }, $myArray);
```

If you don't have php 5.3, you are left with having to declare the function before hand and passing the function name to array_map()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bit more OOP:ish approach using iterators.

```
class TrainedDogIterator implements Iterator {
    // implement methods on http://php.net/iterator
    public function current() {
        $dog = current($this->dogs); // $this->dogs would be your objects
        $trained_dog = $this->_trainDog($dog);
        return $trained_dog;
    }
    private function _trainDog($dog) {
        // do something with dog
        return $dog;
    }
}
```

Use it where you would use `$data` in your example.

```
$di = new TrainedDogIterator($dogs);
foreach($di as $dog) {
    // $dog is trained
}
```

Comment: This is a good/different approach on the problem, so thanks - could come in handy for other things as well.  In this case I'm using a reused function that returns the array of objects, which in other cases need to be as-is.  Though, implementing this approach may put the functionality in a more appropriate place in the code.

Comment: @pssdbt: the code was kind of a long shot, glad you enjoyed it :) If you give a bigger image of your system, you'd get more feedback about the overall design but I agree that you marked the right answer as correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

TMTOWTDI, `array_walk` works similarly to `array_map`, but modifies the array in-place. Though `array_map` has the advantage of supporting multiple arrays:

https://www.php.net/array_walk