# Calling Method of array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object, methods

How can I call methods from an array of objects (that hold an array of objects). I read: [Get array with results of object method on each item in an array of objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835791/get-array-with-results-of-object-method-on-each-item-in-an-array-of-objects-in-p) but could not get it.

Here is my testcode: the first object holds attributes, then an object holds a record of the multiple attributes.

```
/*--------------------------------- */
class SqliteAttribute {

    private $_fieldname = '';
    private $_fieldvalue = '';
    private $_type = 'TEXT';
    private $_key = true;

    function __construct($fieldname, $fieldvalue, $text, $key) {
        $this->_fieldname  = $fieldname;
        $this->_fieldvalue = $fieldvalue;
        $this->_text       = $text;
        $this->_key        = $key;
    }

    function AsArray() {
        $tempArray = array('fieldname'     => $this->_fieldname,
                           'fieldvalue'    => $this->_fieldvalue,
                           'type'          => $this->_type,
                           'key'           => $this->_key
        );
        return $tempArray;
    }
}

/*--------------------------------- */
class SqliteRecord {

    private $_attributes = array();

    function __construct() {
    }

    function AddAttribute($fieldname, $fieldvalue, $text, $key) {
        $attribute          = new SqliteAttribute($fieldname, $fieldvalue, $text, $key);
        $this->attributes[] = $attribute;
        var_dump($this->_attributes); // shows it!
    }

    function AsArray() {
        $temp_array = array();
        var_dump($this->_attributes); // shows nothing
        foreach ($this->_attributes as $key => $value) {
            $temp_array[] = $value->AsArray();
        }
        return $temp_array;
    }

}
```

And I call it like this

```
function updateFiles($files, $rootpath) {
    $recordset = new SqliteRecordSet;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $record = new SqliteRecord;
        $record->AddAttribute('Path', $file[0], 'TEXT', true);

        print_r($record->AsArray()); // shows nothing       
    }

    $recordset->insertIfNotExist_index();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->attributes vs $this->_attributes

you should always develop code with error reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors on. php would have notified you of your mistake here.

Comment: *argh* you are right *argh argh argh* (just to note that i spend some hours on this searching in wrong directions)

Comment: p.s. I have error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); but did not show

Comment: either it never got set, or you have other code that unset it, or you have mucked with php's error handler.